# Access denied when bulk inserting from network share

Tags: sql-server, windows

I get this when I try to do a bulk insert of a file from a network share:

`Cannot bulk load because the file "\\remotepc\folder\file.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).`

What I have checked:

- I am able to bulk insert that file when I copy it to the local file system
- SQL Server runs under a domain account, not NT SERVICE\SQLSERVER
- That network share grants read permission to all domain users
- I am able to open the file in a text editor from that domain account SQL Server is running as
- I am able to list the folder's contents with `EXEC xp_dirtree '\\remotepc\folder\', 1, 1`

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: How do you connect to your SQL Server to perform BULK INSERT? Do you use SQL Server authentication, or Windows authentication?

Comment: Can you check if xp_cmdshell is setup to use a proxy account?

Comment: Hi Slava, thank you for your question.

Comment: I was using Windows authentification. But:
- Following your question, I created a new query, copied paste the code I was trying yesterday and connected to the server using SQL authentication
- Then it worked.
- Then I went back to Windows Authentication and it worked again (from that new Query)
- Then I tried the code in yesterday's query window, and it still does not work, no matter the authentication type

Sorry if that sounds confused. I am probably missing something, will update later if I figure it out.

Comment: run this command to verify that that you are using the correct user:
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'whoami'

Comment: `EXEC xp_cmdshell 'whoami'` returns the Domain account.

Comment: So now I put that bulk insert statement into an SP which I call from a query in SSMS. And the error is back. Right before the bulk insert statement in the SP, I execute `xp_cmdshell 'whoami'` and the name of the domain account, which has read access to the folder, does show up.

Answer (score 0):

I was having problem with bulk insert. Change the connection protocol from named pipe to tcp/ip resolved the issue.
Altough i was using a sql authentication, not  Windows authentication.

From the client machine, the application was using named pipe and the management studio was using  a tcp/ip.

The client configuration for 32bit was the cause.